# Where is the log from repairing an Outlook 2011 database?

Tags: macos, logging, microsoft-outlook-2011

Where is the log from repairing an Outlook 2011 database?

I have a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

### Outlook for Mac provides the option to turn on logging for certain features, such as the following:

- Autodiscover service
- Microsoft Exchange (folder and itemUnits of information in Outlook, such as e-mail messages, calendar events, contacts, tasks, and notes. synchronization)
- Microsoft Exchange Calendar
- LDAPAn acronym for Lightweight Directory Access Protocol, a protocol that provides access to Internet directories. transactions

### Turn on logging:

1. On the Window menu, click Error Log.
2. In the Errors window, click Settings
3. Select the Turn on logging for troubleshooting check box, and then click OK.

### Notes

- Data files that have the name **Microsoft Outlook_Troubleshooting_0.log** are written to the desktop.
- Outlook does not include authentication information in the data files.
- Outlook appends new log entries to the data file until the file is either moved or deleted.

I was able to find this [Source](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/admin/item/cc82d660-9a9b-41ab-ab1c-b5c5db85e560?category=c9277f2c-d467-450c-8ea5-e1845ee6524a) by searching for "Outlook 2011 Log" on any search engine within 10 seconds.

---

### [I also found this which seems to apply to this situation](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1433428)

---

> There is no log. Rebuilding the database does not always fix your
>   problems. If the first time failed, multiple rebuilds will only make
>   the problem worse.
>
> ### Rebuild Basics:
>
> - Do Not Rebuild Identities with Exchange and IMAP accounts. Delete the    accounts (this deletes the cache files in Outlook). Do the
>     rebuild    then add back accounts. Better yet start over in a new
>     Identity. If    the rebuild does not work then you could sync unwanted
>     changes or    deletions to your server and lose data.
> - Make sure you have plenty of free space on your drive. Make sure that    you have at least three times as much hard disk space
>     available as    the current size of your Outlook identity PLUS 10%
>     free for virtual    memory.
> - Rebuilding does not fix all issues. It can make some problems worse.    Even though the Database Utility will make a backup, I
>     advise making    a copy in the Finder first.
> - You can delete the rebuild version after you are satisfied with the    results. This copy will be named like this: Main Identity [Backed up
>     1-21-2012 13.35]
>
> Tip: If your Identity will open, before you rebuild, check "On My
>   Computer"Inbox and Sent folders to be sure they are under the 2GB
>   limit. Generally this is less than 10,000 messages but with large
>   attachments could be less. Make subfolders e.g. Inbox 2011, Inbox
>   2010, Sent 2011, Sent 2010 etc to help reduce the number of messages
>   in a folder. (Check for any large archive folders you might have in
>   addition to Inbox and Sent).